# Code is running with console tool in browser but not from itself?

Tags: javascript, html

I got this code for my js file:

```
var flkty = new Flickity( '.main-gallery', {
  cellAlign: 'left',
  contain: true,
  wrapAround: true,
  prevNextButtons: false,
  autoPlay: 5000
});
```

I saved it and when my site is loading it's correctly showing up in the head tag. However nothing happens. When I open the console of the browser developer tool and paste the code there, then it's working correctly. What can cause this and how can I fix this?

Comment: is that inside a document ready?

Comment: I just saved the code as a .js file.

Comment: then go ahead with @kartikmajo solution

Answer (score 4):

That's because this is never called. Put this in window.onload(which will execute this function when page loads)

```
window.onload = function() {
  var flkty = new Flickity( '.main-gallery', {
    cellAlign: 'left',
    contain: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    prevNextButtons: false,
    autoPlay: 5000
  });
};
```

Or if you are using jquery. This will also work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var flkty = new Flickity( '.main-gallery', {
    cellAlign: 'left',
    contain: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    prevNextButtons: false,
    autoPlay: 5000
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah OK that makes sense now. Just started with js. Thank you! Edit: now it's working.

Comment: @kartikmaji it is called, but before .main-gallery dom elements are loaded